# How do I hook up a cross platform Flutter app with Azure AD

Tags: flutter, azure-active-directory

I have a cross platform application (mobile, desktop and web) created in Flutter that I would like to set up to be authenticated with Azure AD.

I know that there are some packages that you can add for mobile and maybe even for web but I am unable to find a working solution for desktop.

I thought that I could open the browser on the device and use that to sign the user in, but it would need a URI to redirect to when the user is authenticated and for the application to be able to get the token that I can then use to make calls to my API. I can't see how that would work though, due to the application being hosted on the users device and not on a server with a set IP like with websites.

Any possible solutions or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @RahulKumarShaw-MT Thank you for your answer. It definitely lead me down the correct path. But I ended up using a couple of different tutorials to create a solution and I would like to post the solution in more detail soon. Thank you once again for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using a combination of [this](https://medium.com/@segaud.kevin/facebook-oauth-login-flow-with-flutter-9adb717c9f2e) older tutorial for Facebook authentication along with Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#refresh-the-access-token) on how to get a token for native apps to create a small authenticating service seen below.

I used the following pub packages:

- url_launcher
- flutter_dotenv
- http

**Auth Service:**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';
import 'package:research_library_viewer/Models/Token.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class AuthenticationService {
  String tenant = dotenv.env['MSAL_TENANT']!;
  String clientId = dotenv.env['MSAL_CLIENT_ID']!;
  String clientSecret = dotenv.env['MSAL_CLIENT_SECRET']!;
  String redirectURI = dotenv.env['MSAL_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URI']!;
  String scope = dotenv.env['MSAL_CLIENT_SCOPE']!;
  String authority = dotenv.env['MSAL_AUTHORITY_URI']!;

  Future<Stream<String>> _server() async {
    final StreamController<String> onCode = StreamController();
    HttpServer server =
        await HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.loopbackIPv4, 8080);
    server.listen((HttpRequest request) async {
      final String? code = request.uri.queryParameters["code"];
      request.response
        ..statusCode = 200
        ..headers.set("Content-Type", ContentType.html.mimeType)
        ..write("<html><h1>You can now close this window</h1></html>");
      await request.response.close();
      await server.close(force: true);
      if (code != null) {
        onCode.add(code);
        await onCode.close();
      }
    });
    return onCode.stream;
  }

  String getAuthUrl() {
    String authUrl =
        "http://$authority/$tenant/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=$clientId&response_type=code&redirect_uri=$redirectURI&response_mode=query&scope=$scope";
    return authUrl;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> getTokenParameters(String token, bool refresh) {
    Map<String, dynamic> tokenParameters = <String, dynamic>{};
    tokenParameters["client_id"] = clientId;
    tokenParameters["scope"] = scope;
    tokenParameters["client_secret"] = clientSecret;

    if (refresh) {
      tokenParameters["refresh_token"] = token;
      tokenParameters["grant_type"] = "refresh_token";
    } else {
      tokenParameters["code"] = token;
      tokenParameters["redirect_uri"] = redirectURI;
      tokenParameters["grant_type"] = "authorization_code";
    }

    return tokenParameters;
  }

  Future<Token> getToken() async {
    String url = getAuthUrl();
    Stream<String> onCode = await _server();
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw "Could not launch $url";
    }
    final String code = await onCode.first;
    final Map<String, dynamic> tokenParameters =
        getTokenParameters(code, false);
    final response = await http.post(
        Uri.https(
          'login.microsoftonline.com',
          '$tenant/oauth2/v2.0/token',
        ),
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body: tokenParameters);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return tokenFromJson(response.body);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to acquire token');
    }
  }

  Future<Token> refreshToken(String? refreshToken) async {
    if (refreshToken == null) {
      return getToken();
    } else {
      final Map<String, dynamic> tokenParameters = getTokenParameters(refreshToken, true);
      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.https(
          'login.microsoftonline.com',
          '$tenant/oauth2/v2.0/token',
        ),
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body: tokenParameters);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return tokenFromJson(response.body);
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to acquire token');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Token:**

```
import 'dart:convert';

Token tokenFromJson(String str) {
  final jsonData = json.decode(str);
  return Token.fromJson(jsonData);
}

class Token {
  String accessToken;
  String tokenType;
  num? expiresIn;
  String? refreshToken;
  String? idToken;
  String? scope;

  Token({
    required this.accessToken,
    required this.tokenType,
    this.expiresIn,
    this.refreshToken,
    this.idToken,
    this.scope,

  });

  factory Token.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Token(
        accessToken: json["access_token"],
        tokenType: json["token_type"],
        expiresIn: json["expires_in"],
        refreshToken: json["refresh_token"],
        idToken: json["id_token"],
        scope: json["scope"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "access_token": accessToken,
        "token_type": tokenType,
        "expires_in": expiresIn,
        "refresh_token": refreshToken,
        "id_token": idToken,
        "scope": scope,
      };
}
```

I think that this could still be improved a lot, but it is definitely something to start with if you are sitting with a similar challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Found an MS document you can follow to add Azure Authentication in your Desktop application.

Refer this : [Sign-in a user with the Microsoft Identity Platform in a WPF Desktop application and call an ASP.NET Core Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/1-desktop-app-calls-web-api/)

There is also another way for the same but with Azure AD B2C : [Configure authentication in a sample WPF desktop app by using Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-wpf-desktop-app)

The application registration and architecture are illustrated in the following diagrams:

[image]